# What is the formula for a function that can generate the following graph?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, functions

What is an example of a function formula and its graph that shows that when something increases to infinity, the other thing decreases to infinity?

For example:

> f(x)=-x

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSvS9.png)

In `f(x)=-x` `x` and `y` can reach to zero so this is not the graph I'm looking for; you may think I'm asking about this function `f(x)=-x-1`

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2r4R.png)

I want to have all the possible values for `f(x)=-x` but without having `x` and `y` equal to zero.

I think the graph would be like this, but what is a formula of a function that can generate the following graph?

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mskeb.png)

Comment: If at $x=-1$ graph have vertical line, then it cant be a function.

Comment: It is plainly $y=-x-1$.

Comment: @zkutch In  x=−1 what exactly is decreasing while increasing something?

Comment: Your last graph is not a function as there are multiple values of y for x=-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?
$y=\begin{cases}
-x, & x<-1, x\geq1 \\
-2x-1, & -1\leq x<0 \\
-1, & 0\leq x<1
\end{cases}$

[image: graph]

Comment: I like the graph; it would be great if you could tell me in which software I can use your code to get that graph.

Comment: I used desmos https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Comment: In a brace, you have three lines, but in Desmos, in a brace, when I press enter, it doesn't give me a new line; it creates a new empty box. How can I get a new line inside the brace?

There is a share button in Desmos; can you send the link?

Comment: write them as separate functions https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mi5irfxbxg